# Load early created object when servlet request coming

Tags: java, jsp, http

I am creating Map with data when the 1st request coming to servlet, then return it to JSP page, from that JSP page there is a another request coming to servlet and i want to have early created Map with data when 2nd request came, otherwise i have to load data again to new Map,

Is there any way to do this ? , i cant parse Map objects via HTTP request and i'am using Java

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways I can think of :

1. Put the data in the `request` scope and `forward` the requests using `RequestDispatcher`. This won't work if the requests are not forwarded and a new request is created.
2. Put the data in the `session` scope , the data will be valid through out the session for a particular client.
3. Put the data as `ServletContext` attribute , visible to all requests, sessions and throughout the web app.